# ASP.net core Authentication token becomes invalid randomly on hostgator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, hosting, web-hosting

I'm having issues with hosting my website on a windows server by Hostgator and I'm not sure where the problem lies.

The issue is whenever I login to my website I built, and I try to process an order, or go through the checkout screens on my website, it fails because the authentication token is invalid. It does not expire, and works on localhost, and also works on azure hosting. (I know little to nothing about azure hosting and would rather stick to hostgator windows hosting).

I don't see any error messages anywhere I look.

Update: This doesn't seem to be the issue anymore. "I did notice the asp.net framework version is 4.8.0 and my application is 5.0 but other than that, I can't see any other reason for this not to work."

If you want to see the issue for yourself:

shop.vents-us.com
Username: testing@shop.vents-us.com
Password: HelloWorld1!
Fake credit card to use: 4242424242424242 424 42424

As you try to complete the checkout, it will log you out.

I'll update as I keep researching. Thanks!

Update: It is not on heavy processing like previously thought. It seems almost random. If I am switching between screens that require login, it kicks me out within a couple minutes. I checked my timeout, and it's set to 30 minutes.

Update: Still having the issue even after making the deployment mode self-contained.
[image: Deployment Settings]

Update: Here's the packages installed on the server from hostgator:
.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Update: I have managed to get the bug on film
[image]

Comment: 4.8 is much older than you think... (older than any asp.net-core version).  Try publishing as self-contained and see if that fixes it.  (that way you're guaranteed to have the correct framework)

Comment: This is what Hostgator just replied to me and said to do. Now it's giving me http error 500.32 HTTP Error 500.32 - Failed to load .NET Core host. Common solutions to this issue:
The app was likely published for a different bitness than w3wp.exe/iisexpress.exe is running as.

Comment: I got it to publish, But no luck. Same issue

Comment: Hostgator needs to install the asp.net-core hosting module.

Comment: I updated the post with the runtimes that are installed. Would it be any of those?

Comment: no... once you're self contained you don't even need any run-times installed.  The server needs to have the hosting module installed.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243098/discussion-between-scott-uphus-and-pcalkins).

Comment: chances are high that you will need a dedicated server for this.  The shared server packages probably do not include support for core.

Comment: Hi Scott, Please make sure that your hosting provider support .net core and make sure you deploy your .net core with self-contained mode, it should be fix your issue. You may also refer to this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-error-500-30-asp-net-core-app-failed-to-start/.